# Flipping nodes in a pie chart - more specific

Tags: tikz-pgf

I only want to flip the nodes for "Pecan" and "Peach" in the pie chart.  I am providing the same code as I provided in another post.  One reply was to change the command from

```
\path (O) -- node[rotate=220]{Pecan} (220:3);
```

to

```
\path (O) -- node[rotate=45]{Pecan} (220:3);.
```

In particular, changing `rotate=220` to `rotate=45` flips the node.  Why does `rotate=45` work?  Would `rotate=50`, `rotate=67`, and `rotate=-12` also work?  Another member suggested to just use `sloped` or `sloped, allow upside down` and one of these will give me the display that I want. Is that correct?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\draw (O) circle (3);
\draw (O) -- (0:3);
\draw (O) -- (120:3);
\draw (O) -- (210:3);
\draw (O) -- (230:3);
\draw (O) -- (270:3);
\draw (O) -- (310:3);

\path (O) -- node{Vanilla} (60:3);
\path (O) -- node{Chocolate} (165:3);
\path (O) -- node[rotate=220]{Pecan} (220:3);
\path (O) -- node[rotate=250]{Peach} (250:3);
\path (O) -- node{Mint} (290:3);
\path (O) -- node[rotate=335]{Strawberry} (335:3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's late over here, I'll post an answer tomorrow but yes, those will change the angle the word is rotated.  220 will make the word appear upside down.

Comment: @Alenanno  I am leaving now, too.  Where are you?  I am in New York.

Answer (score 3):

> Why does rotate=45 work? Would rotate=50, rotate=67, and rotate=-12 also work?

Let's start from the premise that words (i.e. nodes) rotate around the center, which is the default anchor. So unless you specify a different anchor, they will "spin". The default angle is 0, which is a straight line from left to right.

Positive angles will rotate the word **counterclockwise**, like this:

[image: counterclockwise]

While negative angles will rotate it **clockwise**, like this:

[image: clockwise]

So in the code below I will use the *counterclockwise* motion (it's easier with positive values).

> Another member suggested to just use sloped or sloped, allow upside down and one of these will give me the display that I want. Is that correct?

`sloped` basically is a property of a node along a diagonal `path` (or `draw`) which follows it's inclination. Without adding this option, the node will be typeset written horizontally (regardless of the inclination of the path). `allow upside down` in this case would be discouraged because the word will appear... upside down (not very comfortable to read).

However you can create your piechart with a foreach command that greatly simplifies and reduces your code. I changed the documentclass to `standalone` and added the package `amsmath` just for this example, but it should work with `\documentclass{amsart}` as well (tested it). If you have any questions, ask below:

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\draw (O) circle (3);

\foreach \angle/\taste [remember=\angle as \lasta (initially 0)] in {
    120/Vanilla,
    210/Chocolate,
    230/Pecan,
    270/Peach,
    310/Mint,
    360/Strawberry}
{
        \coordinate (\angle) at (\angle:3);
        \draw (O) -- (\angle);
        \path (O) -- node[sloped]{\taste} ({(\lasta+\angle)/2}:3);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Basically whenever you see `\something`, that's a variable. Since the `\foreach` is a loop, for each time `\angle` and `\taste` will change. They will change together (they are coupled in that list).

This is what it does:

1. For each current angle in that list (called `\angle`), create a coordinate called by the angle itself, positioned at the angle and the distance.

   ```
    \coordinate (\angle) at (\angle:3);
   ```

   Also, remember the last angle as `\lasta`.
2. Then draw a path from `O` to the coordinate `\angle` defined above. This will draw lines to each angle that I specified in the list (in other words, the pie slices).
3. Finally, create a path (path is invisible unless you specify otherwise) from `O` to the average of the last angle (`\lasta`) and the current angle (`\angle`). The average is calculated doing `({(\lasta+\angle)/2}:3)`, so for example, in the first loop (starting from 0), it will become  `({(\0+120)/2}:3)`, so `(60:3)`. And indeed, `Vanilla` is at 60 degrees.

Comment: Is there special reason to use 'midway' in node options? The same result is obtained without this option. Also the definition of coordinate '\angle' seems to be superfluous. Is it not enough to just say '\draw (O) -- (\angle:3)'?

Comment: @Zarko You're right about the `midway` option, but no the coordinate is not superfluous. I tried it as first and it throws an error, since it believes that `\angle` is a node name, which is not, but defining the coordinate makes it a node name, thus removing the error.

Comment: Interesting, at me this work (without coordinate definition and with draw as I say im my previous comment). I use MikTeX 2.9 (recent version) and CVS version from July 2014 of TikZ. If this matter.

Comment: @Zarko You're right, it's weird that it doesn't. I currently don't know why though. :D

Comment: @Alenanno  Thanks for the code.  I am not familiar with `foreach` statements.  All I got from it is to use the option `sloped` for get "Pecan," "Peach," and "Strawberry" typeset properly.  I am sure that for most members of `tex.stackexchange`, this is the code they would use.  For me, at this time, I will issue separate commands to print the different flavors.

Comment: @Alenanno  Oh, you're Italian.  Are you in Italy?  When you replied to me last night, it was 9:00 in New York.  That would be the middle of the night in Italy!

Comment: @user74973 The foreach is very easy! I'll add an explanation if you prefer. But you don't need to understand it *now*. You can just copy/paste it in your document.

Comment: @Alenanno  If you want to explain the syntax for the `\foreach` command, I will read it.  I read about it in the manual.  At the time, there were other aspects of `TikZ` that I knew that I needed to learn; so, I didn't understand the examples provided.

Comment: @Alenanno   Are you in Italy?  I am not stalking.  I am just curious - you seem to be on this site all the time!

Comment: @Alenanno  I can (and probably will) delete these texts about the country in which you reside.

Comment: @user74973 My country is not exactly a secret but yes I am in Italy. Sometimes I post late in the night that's probably why it seems I'm always online. :) It's better to have "casual chat" in the [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends), while reserving comments for the question at hand. (No problem though.)

Comment: @Alenanno   I just went to the site.  (I had to log-in again.)  What link do I use to get to `tex.stachexchange` members or `math.stackexchange` members?

Comment: @user74973 Added explanation.